# How to 'null' check in javascript(node-webkit)?

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

I'm developing window application for comparing source code with node-webkit and I want to check null function.

my code is

```
function click1() {
      if(swap == true)
        var lines1 = $('textarea1').val().split('\n'); //compare1
        var lines2 = $('textarea2').val().split('\n'); //compare2

        if (lines1.length == lines2.length) {
             for (var i=0;i<lines1.length;i++) {
                 if(lines1[i] == lines2[i]) {
                      var keys = lines1[i].match(/\b[\w\d]*/g);
                      if(keys[0] == null) { //**problem line**
                          alert('This line is null');
                      } else {
                          alert(keys[0]);
                      }
                 }
             }
```

If i execute this click event, error occured.

Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property '0' of null

How I can fix this problem..

help me

ps. I tried `keys[0] === null`, `typeof keys[0] == 'null'`, `!keys[0]` etc...

Answer (score 1):

just use this:

```
if(keys[0]) {
  alert(keys[0]);
} else {
  alert('This line is null');
}
```

Comment: `.match` may return `null`, `null[0]` will throw that error. You have to guard against that case too.

Comment: i believe keys is not array. remove the "[0]".

Comment: Oh, Thanks Dr.Stitch!! i solved problem thanks to your solution. but if key is not null, keys[0] is worked

Comment: great! happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

its not `keys[0]` that's null. its `keys`. Look at the error, it can't read property `0` of `null` meaning it can't read the `0` property of the null variable `keys`. Your regular expression isn't matching anything, so it returns `null`.

solution:

`if (keys && keys[0])`

Comment: Thanks to your adivce. I understand keys not array, but if keys is not null, keys[0] is exist. Why existed [0] ?

Comment: I think I understand your question. For the answer I shall point you to this link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). 
`match` will return an array **if it finds a match** and `null` if **no matches are found**. It's best to learn how the method works before you agonize over it.

Answer (score 0):

array[index] is null or undefined.

```
if (keys[0] == 'undefined' || keys[0] == null) {
   alert('This line is null');
} else {
   alert(keys[0]);
}
```

array[index] is null and undefined.

```
if (keys[0] == 'undefined' && keys[0] == null) {
   alert('This line is null');
} else {
   alert(keys[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to advice Jakir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!keys || keys.length === 0) { //**problem line**
  alert('This line is null');
}else {
  alert(keys[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your adivice saikumar!